# does having encoder/decoders in 433MHz rf links improve range and reduce noise?

Tags: arduino, rf, 433mhz

with the use of encoders and decoders I'm able to interface more than one RF link pair at the same time, this is what the usage of an encoder looks like to me.

Are there more uses to it than this?

Does it help us to improve range and reduce noise?

Comment: Well, if instead of an OOK modulation you use a more sophisticated modulation yes, you can reduce the noise outside your band or you can increase the range. If the modulation is the same I don't think you will be able to increase the performances. What kind of encoders/decoders are you using?

Comment: I am not set up on the usage of encoder yet I was thinking of HT12E and HT12D pair maybe?
My task is to create a RC car. Which uses PWM signals for motor control over L293D.

Comment: Ok, with those encoders you won't be able to increase the range or reduce the noise, since they simply provide a "handshaking" between the two. Anyway, since you want to create a RC car, why don't you move towards bluetooth? You'll get a stronger protection, immunity to other devices (e.g. gate openers) and most important you will be able to control the car from smartphones. Nowadays BT modules are simple to use (usually they just have a serial interface)

Comment: Then what is a good encoder to use in that case? there's no mention about the PWM capability on the HT12 pair. If i use that would I be able to send PWM signals? I am doing this with RF is to learn it. I will somehow in a later project use Bluetooth. Since I have used XBee in another one of my projects it may be a lot simpler right? than RF i meant

Comment: Well, I'm not really into RF, but I think that if you have a board which can modulate into OOK modulation you can't change it. You should look for other RF modules with a better modulation scheme, but I don't know any since when I need RF support I just use a pre-made board (nRF24l01, BT, APC220)

Comment: the modules which i am using have ASK and with the HT12 encoder decoder pair, I will not be able to increase the range but it should support PWM right?

Comment: Well, I don't think you will be able to get any usable pwm. Looking at the datasheet of the HT12E, you have an oscillator frequency of 3kHz, 4 oscillator cycles per bit, 24.3 bit per word, so you will get one word in 97.2 clock cycles, i.e. 32.4ms. If you want to have a 8 values PWM (you will be able to set the pwm at 12.5%, 25%, 37.5%, 50% and so on) then the PWM period will be 0.259s, i.e. a PWM frequency of roughly 4Hz. I don't know your motors, but I think 4Hz is a very low frequency for PWM...

Comment: I just have N20 DC geared motors, four of them. 3v-9v. Its best If i have 8bit PWM.

Comment: 8 bit PWM? then it's 256 levels... So PWM period of 8.3 seconds... It's absolutely useless. So, no. You can't use that encoder for PWM. I suggest you to implement your own encoding scheme with microcontrollers. You'll have to implement your own handshaking (or better just addressing) and then serially transfer the value you want to use, so you can reproduce the PWM.

Comment: So i guess Its better to have VirtualWire library to do this with a Status machine than this right? then I'd need two micro controllers.

I was trying to get this working without another MCU. I needed to write the PWM signal with `digitalWrite()` **[arduino]** and read it on the other side.

Comment: In this case, I think that if you really need to use HT12E and HT12D you'd better use a 4-wire asynchronous connection, choosing the protocol you prefer. This way you can send a "packet" of 8 4-bits packets, each describing the high and low nibble of the PWM of one motor, then use the PWM generator to generate them. But in this case I suggest you to simplify everything and connect the RF transceiver directly to the serial port of the microcontroller. Much easier, less hardware...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment:

How do you intend to send the PWM value? You can send a 4 bit value as data between the HT12 pair.

The encoder/decoder do not help with the range but you get rid of false transmissions. The HT12 encoder sends the message three times and the address needs to be the same on both decoder and encoder before a Valid Transmission is recognized by the decoder.

Comment: i'd like if I have at least 256 levels on the PWM pins, just like a normal Arduino would have. could I do that with this? 4 bit seems a bit too low for that right?
16 levels is okay, but it would be better if i have more

Comment: The address is 8 bits and data 4 bits so I don't think it is possible. You can also check out the Virtualwire protocol. It let's you send RF without any encoder/decoder but you need an MCU on each end. See https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_VirtualWire.html

Comment: So i guess i cant use `digitalWrite()`and write PWM data on a single pin of the encoder and plug it directly to say a servo to have it working right? too bad. VirtualWire needs two MCUs that is the problem, If i can get this working with one MCU it would be really great